# Is this true $n!\leq(\frac{5n+7}{12})^n,n∈N$?

Tags: inequality, summation, factorial, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Is the following inequality true?

For all $n\in \Bbb N$ prove that:
$$n!\leq\left(\frac{5n+7}{12}\right)^n.$$

I know the answer,but I want to see other people how to prove the problem.

In my proof I used $\frac{5n+7}{12}=\frac{\frac{n+1}2+\frac{n+2}3}2\geq \sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}6}$
$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right)}$
$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k+1)}$
$\ge\sqrt{\sqrt[n]{(n!)^2}}=\sqrt[n]{n!}$.

Comment: Where is this problem originated ?

Comment: You can check that for some values in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/)

Comment: Even though reduced to $5/12$ of the original value, it is still roughly $n^n$, which grows way faster than $n!$, no doubt there is $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ this holds. The trick I guess is to prove $n_0$ is $1$

Comment: This is my first post problem,I am just trying

Comment: @JamesJ You should add what you tried or your thoughts. Many questions get closed due to the lack of showing effort.

Comment: I know the answer,but I want to see other people how to prove the problem.

Comment: @JamesJ Ah alright! You should point it out as you did now to avoid any problem.

Comment: @Scientifica See please my proof and comments under the proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you. I saw it and saw his edit to the question. I just told him that so he avoids getting his question closed (you see that there are 4 votes for closing his question; one more and it would have been closed).

Comment: @Robert,I think use GM,a(n)=(1+1/n)^n->e,as n->∞,
monotonic increasing,so that the GM:(a(1)a(2)...a(n))^(1/n)=(n+1)/(n!)^(1/n)->e ,but this is equal form,I don't know how to go next.

Comment: @TStancek: $n!$ is asymptotic to $n^{1/2}(n/e)^n$, so the margin is not so large. ($12/5=2.4$)

Comment: @TStancek: your "grows way faster than $n!$" is wrong. Both the given functions grow like $(n/c)^n$, which is significantly lower than $n^n$, and the factorial has an extra growth factor so one needs to check where the breakeven point falls.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$\frac{1\cdot n+2(n-1)+...+n\cdot1}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{(n!)^2}$$ or
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}}\right)^n\geq n!.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{5n+7}{12}\geq\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}},$$
which is $$(n-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

$$1\cdot n+2(n-1)+...+n\cdot1=\sum_{k=1}^nk(n-k+1)=$$
$$=(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^nk-\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=(n+1)\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\cdot(3n+3-2n-1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.$$

Comment: You also can make three times that obtain this :(4n+5)/9>=(n!)^(1/n)

Comment: @JamesJ It's weaker because $\frac{4}{9}>\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: Yes it is:(n!)^(1/n)<=(5n+7)/12<=(4n+5)/9<=(n+1)/2

Comment: I think if (5n+7)/12 is the best number?

Comment: @JamesJ We can get a best estimation by the Stirling approximation.